# Error when trying to use value stored in array in digitalWrite()

Tags: arduino-uno, seven-segment-display

Im driving a 7-segment display using Arduino and want to display some letters. I passed the index of array -> digitPins (which has stored the ports connected to Arduino) in the digital write function but it doesn't work. However, it works when I use it somewhere else or if I create a local array and then pass that array as an argument.

```cpp
void printA(){
    turnOFFAll(digitPins); //To reset display before displaying a letter
    digitalWrite(digitPins[1], HIGH); //Trying just one for now, gives error
};
```

```cpp
Error:  invalid types 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}[int]' for array subscript
    digitalWrite(digitPins[1], HIGH);
```

However, this works well. Even though Im doing the same thing except using the variable 'i' in place of the constant that I was using and setting the output to LOW rather than HIGH.

```cpp
void turnOFFAll(byte digitPins[]){
    for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i++){
        digitalWrite(digitPins[i], LOW);
    }
}
```

Comment: change type of `digitPins` from `uint8_t digitPins[]` to `int digitPins[]`